# Would a bitcoin "cleaning" service be legal in New Zealand?

Tags: internet, new-zealand, cryptocurrency, money-laundering, money-service

I'd like to create a piece of software or service which takes someone's Bitcoin, goes through a process of "cleaning" it (making it untraceable) and then returning it.

Provided the purpose of the application is not for any kind of criminal usage, could this be legally published as a service?

Comment: Can you give an example of legitimate use of a service like this, and what measures you would take to prevent criminal use?

Comment: Related: [First Bitcoin “mixer” penalized by FinCEN for violating anti-money laundering laws](https://www.fincen.gov/news/news-releases/first-bitcoin-mixer-penalized-fincen-violating-anti-money-laundering-laws) (2020)

Answer (score 4):

The applicable law is the New Zealand [Anti-Money Laundering](https://www.dia.govt.nz/AML-CFT-Act-and-Regulations) law. The [regulations describing exactly what is covered](http://www.legislation.govt.nz/regulation/public/2011/0222/latest/DLM3845896.html) don't mention Bitcoin cleaning, but the "wire transfer" and "currency exchange" bits probably cover such a thing. I certainly wouldn't like to be the test case.

There was also [this case](https://www.coindesk.com/eu-authorities-crack-down-on-bitcoin-transaction-mixer) in Europe.